# Structure to store Animated SVG in MongoDB using GeoJson

Tags: javascript, mongodb, animation, svg, geojson

I'm looking for best possible solution to store animated svg to mongodb using geojson.

**Aim**

Store Animated cartoons svg's which performing action according to predefined requirement, user can change action during the viewing option. And the animation will display in real-time from db.

**Requirement:**

I'm trying to build database structure to store animated svg, let me explain you what I meant by animated svg. For example a cartoon have four action to perform under animation, each action would be separately store in db but all four would create a single animation together by calling from db. and it will display as animated svg, User can pause this and can see each action separately, depend on requirement.

**Question**

1. Possible way to store each action related to different cartoon using geoJson.
2. Over All structure to deal such requirement.
3. Can I create animated cartoon on demand through out mongodb, GeoJson and D3?
4. There is any other option available to display and store animation to database and display as realtime?
5. Preferable language(s) and tool(s)?

I will try to update my question if any progress come across and also look forward to hearing from you if you have any question to ask.